# Issues with Creating application as a Web Service vs Regular MVC

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, web-applications, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a web application. The requirement is that is the future the application may also be used by other web application and mobile application.

My idea was the build the whole business logic layer as rest web service and build web client to consume this.

Later I can use the same thing in case I want to build a mobile client or give it to external parties. This saves me from writing a separate api code.

1. Is this the correct way?
2. Will it have any performance impact?
3. What is the primary reason of not adopting such an approach.?

I am using Java ,spring MVC,spring,hibetnate and Mysql as the development stack

Comment: This question as-is is too broad, but the pattern you're discussing is a very workable design. It does have some performance penalty, but it also makes your code more decoupled, easier to test, and easier to scale horizontally. If you look for resources on "microservices", you'll probably see the sort of design patterns you're looking for.

Comment: I did have a look at microservices, after your suggestion  and the whole idea is making more sense now.I will read more into it